# Check if DateString is valid from List of formats using Java8

Tags: java-8

I am new to Java8

I am trying to check whether a DateString is valid by checking it against a list of acceptable date formats in my application.

I am currently using SimpleDateFormat. 
Is it possible to do this using DateTimeFormatter since I am using Java8?

```
public static boolean isDateValid(String dateValue)
    {
        boolean returnVal = false;
        String[] permissFormats = new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd", "ddMMMyy"}; 
        SimpleDateFormat sdfObj = new SimpleDateFormat();
        sdfObj.setLenient(false); //strict validation
        ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0); 
        for (int i = 0; i < permissFormats.length; i++) {
            sdfObj.applyPattern(permissFormats[i]);
            position.setIndex(0);
            position.setErrorIndex(-1);
            sdfObj.parse(dateValue, position);
            if (position.getErrorIndex() == -1) {
                returnVal = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way which is just replacing with java 8 equivalent.

```
    public static boolean isDateValid(String dateValue)
    {
        boolean returnVal = false;
        String[] permissFormats = new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd", "ddMMMyy"};
         for (int i = 0; i < permissFormats.length; i++) {
            DateTimeFormatter sdfObj = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .parseStrict().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern(permissFormats[i]).toFormatter();
            ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
            position.setIndex(0);
            position.setErrorIndex(-1);
            sdfObj.parse(dateValue, position);
            if (position.getErrorIndex() == -1) {
                returnVal = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I tested with 19JAN17 but the method returned false. I see the exception java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '19JAN17' could not be parsed at index 0
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '19JAN17' could not be parsed at index 2

Comment: DateTimeFormatter is more strict than SimpleDateFormat. Added the case insensitive option to the builder. Try now.

Comment: I see that the 1st pattern yyyy-MM-dd is working but ddMMMyy is not working

Comment: MM for number & MMM for text. So the first one works and second one needed case insensitive option to work in all cases.

Comment: If I put ddMMMyy is placed in first place then it works but yyyy-MM-dd fails. Whichever is the 1st pattern is working correctly. the second pattern is not working